# sorting max to min value in sql is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

i have 1 table for ex table1
and it have columns names: id, name, amount.

```
id name amount
1  abc  20
2  xyz  50
3  pqr  246
```

i want to sort it from max value to min.
i have written this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

but it gives output like this:

```
id name amount
2  xyz  50
3  pqr  246
1  abc  20
```

which is not valid output that i want, i want output like this:

```
id name amount
3  pqr  246
2  xyz  50
1  abc  20
```

so, if anyone know the solution of this problem please give me the solution.

Comment: what is datatype of `amount` ?

Comment: what is the data type of amount column?

Comment: make it `int` or `float` and you are good to go!

Comment: The answer i think would be: the datatype of the field 'amoun' should be a number type (int, float, etc). If you set it to varchar, will be ordered as a varchar, so based on ascii table. You want it in numeric order.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  The two databases are very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing the `amount` as a string, it would appear.

Here are two solutions.  You can convert the values to a number for the sort:

```
order by amount + 0 desc
```

Or, order by the length first and then the value:

```
order by length(amount) desc, amount desc
```

In general, in SQL, you should make use of the built-in types and store values as the appropriate time.  Numbers should be stored as numbers (integers, floats, or decimals).  Dates and times should be stored as date/time types.  And strings can be used for string values.

Comment: If they are only numbers stored as string, then `to_number` should suffice.

Comment: @LalitKumarB . . . I didn't notice the Oracle tag.  In Oracle, `to_number()` would be the right approach.  The first query is sort of specific to MySQL (although it will work in other databases, although other databases will generate an error if `amount` is not numeric).

Answer (score 0):

Its related to wrong datatype.

Make data type of `amount` column as INT or FLOAT.

Answer (score 0):

See the design of the table by using a command such as

```
DESC TABLENAME
```

I suspect your Amount column is text/varchar and not numeric.

Or simply run the following command and then try your query.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN AMOUNT INT
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use appropriate data types for the data to store.

Since the **data type** of `amount` column is string and not numeric, **ORDER BY** sorts it based on the **ASCII** Value.

```
SQL> WITH DATA(ID, NAME, amount) AS(
  2  SELECT 2,  'xyz',  '50' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 3,  'pqr',  '246' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 1,  'abc',  '20' FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT * FROM DATA
  7  ORDER BY amount DESC;

        ID NAM AMO
---------- --- ---
         2 xyz 50
         3 pqr 246
         1 abc 20

SQL>
```

If you have only numeric data stored as string, then you could use **TO_NUMBER** to explicitly convert the string into number while sorting.

```
ORDER BY to_number(amount) DESC
```

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA(ID, NAME, amount) AS(
  2  SELECT 2,  'xyz',  '50' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 3,  'pqr',  '246' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 1,  'abc',  '20' FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT * FROM DATA
  7  ORDER BY to_number(amount) DESC;

        ID NAM AMO
---------- --- ---
         3 pqr 246
         2 xyz 50
         1 abc 20

SQL>
```