# Sort query results by max value (results from max to min)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (tuition_fees) composed of id, uni, undergraduate and postgraduate. the query returns the tuition cost for undergraduate and postgraduate studies and the results of the total sum (undergraduate and postgraduate). How to order these results from max to min values of the total sum.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test')or die ( mysqli_error($connect) ); 
$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 
mysqli_query($connect,$sSQL) 
or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase'); 
$output = '';
$return = '';
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "select t.uni, 
(select  undergraduate from tuition_fees where `uni` = t.uni) as 'undergraduate1',
(select  postgraduate from tuition_fees where `uni` = t.uni) as 'postgraduate2'
from tuition_fees t group by t.uni
";


$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$i=1;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

$return .='<tr>';

$return .=  '<td style="width: 4%; background:#F0F8FF; color:black;" align="center">' . $i . '</td>'; 
$return .='<td style="width: 15%; background:#F0F8FF; color:black;" align="right">'.$row['uni'].'</td>';
$return .='<td style="width: 14%; background:#F0F8FF; color:black;" align="center">'.$row['undergraduate1'].'</td>';
$return .='<td style="width: 14%; background:#F0F8FF; color:black;" align="center">'.$row['postgraduate2'].'</td>';

$totalsum1=$row['undergraduate1']+$row['postgraduate2'];
$return .='<td style="width: 14%; background:#F0F8FF; color:#00008B;" align="center">'.$totalsum1.'</td>';
$return .='</tr>';
$i++;
}
echo "<br/><div style ='font:18px Times New Roman,sans-serif;'> $return</div>";   

?>
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/j13ZRYS

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113544/sorting-max-to-min-value-in-sql-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer; too long for a comment...

For what it's worth, I find this easier to read...

```
$totalsum1=$row['undergraduate1']+$row['postgraduate2'];

$return .= 
'<tr>
  <td style="width: 4%; background:#F0F8FF; color:black;" align="center"> $i </td>
  <td style="width: 15%; background:#F0F8FF; color:black;" align="right"> {$row['uni']} </td>
  <td style="width: 14%; background:#F0F8FF; color:black;" align="center"> {$row['undergraduate1']} </td>
  <td style="width: 14%; background:#F0F8FF; color:black;" align="center"> {$row['postgraduate2']} </td>
  <td style="width: 14%; background:#F0F8FF; color:#00008B;" align="center">$totalsum1</td>
  </tr>';
$i++;
```

Comment: please, (totalsum1) is not column name, its a result of a query